# GroupBy using underscore.js using nested JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js

I am trying to group this JSON by using `BroadCategory` attribute of `category`

```
[{
"brand": "Brand3",
"category": {
    "popularity_index": 7,
    "BroadCategory ": "BroadCategory4",
    "MainCategory": "MainCategory410",
    "GeneralCategory": "GeneralCategory41"
},
"description": "colonialism",
"discount": 17,
"id": 9
}, {
"brand": "Brand2",
"category": {
    "popularity_index": 5,
    "BroadCategory ": "BroadCategory2",
    "MainCategory": "MainCategory210",
    "GeneralCategory": "GeneralCategory21"
},
"description": "desc2",
"discount": 15,
"id": 2
}]
```

I went through [underscore.js - _.groupBy nested attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577578/underscore-js-groupby-nested-attribute) but this has array inside JSON for `location`

I tried something like:

```
var grpArray = _.groupBy(products, function (element) {
   return element.category.BroadCategory;
})
```

but its not working. Why can't I access `BroadCategory` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trim a space "BroadCategory "

```
"BroadCategory ": "BroadCategory2",
```

Change to:

```
"BroadCategory": "BroadCategory2",
```

OR:

```
_.groupBy(products, function (element) {
   return element.category['BroadCategory '];
})
```

Comment: Ahh.My bad.That was close. :) Thanks